# Firebase Cloud Function failed deployment due to Secret Manager access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have my Firebase Cloud Functions deployed for months and even updating code as I go. Suddenly, I am hit with the below error, likely related to my Secrets Manager (GCP).

**Function deployment failed due to a health check failure. This usually indicates that your code was built successfully but failed during a test execution. Examine the logs to determine the cause. Try deploying again in a few minutes if it appears to be transient. This deployment uses Secrets. Ensure that the runtime service account 'myAccount-somID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' has the permission 'roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor' on the project or secrets.**

I am unable to solve this issue despite going through SO suggestion on access issues which I believe I have already given to this account. I have already given Secret Accessor to my service account but yet the deployment is showing otherwise.

Oddly enough, some of my functions were deployed while others have not. The ones that did not get deployed had cors.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to debug the issue albeit without a perfect solution

Previously in my code, I was using a secret key called SOME_KEY (which is stored in my Secret Manager in GCP). Later, I removed this key from my code and deleted the secret key from the Secret Manager.

However, on deployment, it looks like the function is still searching for this secret key, although the runWith secrets in this function was removed.

Adding back the SOME_KEY secret key back to the Secret Manager solves this issue.

Any idea how I can delete a secret key and be able to deploy the code? Seems pointless to have secrets that are not in use and also be charged for them from Google.